# Python - How to count the frequency of each unique key from a column containing a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a very large dataframe containing a column called 'time_words'. Each cell of the column contains a list of dictionaries, for example:

| time_columns |
| --- |
| {'**Yesterday**': {'text': 'Yesterday', 'type': 'DATE', 'value': '2022-04-15'}} |
| {'**Yesterday**': {'text': 'Yesterday', 'type': 'DATE', 'value': '2022-04-16'}, 'Thursday': {'text': 'Thursday', 'type': 'DATE', 'value': '2022-04-14'}} |

How can I efficiently get a table containing the frequency count of the unique keys of the main dictionary like below? (In a table because I want to save the result to a CSV.)

| text | count |
| --- | --- |
| Yesterday | 2 |
| Thursday | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df["time_columns"]
    .explode()
    .value_counts()
    .reset_index(name="count")
    .rename(columns={"index": "text"})
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        text  count
0  Yesterday      2
1   Thursday      1
```

Comment: I tried this, but df["time_columns"].explode() gives me a Key error:0 on his input data ...

Comment: @DanielWeigel What pandas version are you using? I'm on `pandas==1.4.2`

Comment: I guess you re right...my pandas version 0.25.1. I then checked on a virtual env with your pandas version and it worked : ) time to do some upgrades i reckon

Comment: @BobDylan Please check what `pandas` version are you using (possibly upgrading to latest version)

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment, but realized that the problem is that my "dictionaries" are actually strings. Will fix that... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the input data, could you try this ?

```
tmp=pd.concat(([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v,orient='index') for k,v in df['time_columns'].items()]))
tmp['text'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to just iterate through list and save results to new dictionary sth like:

```
res = {}
for dict in df['time_columns']:
    for key in dict.keys():
        if key not in res.keys():
             res[key] = 1
        else:
             res[key] += 1
```

If you know keys in advance you can initialize dict with keys and zeros and  replace if statement inside the loop with just increment.

```
keys = ['Yesterday', 'Thursday', 'etc.']
res = {key: 0 for key in keys}
for dict in df['time_columns']:
    for key in dict.keys():
        res[key] += 1
```

Comment: If you want to convert it to dataframe later do: `res_df = pd.DataFrame({'text': res.keys(), 'count': res.values()})`

Comment: I think this would work too. I realized that the "dictionaries" in my column are not actually dictionaries, but instead strings, so will have to fix that